# Is there a Bonjour SDK for Windows?

Tags: windows, sdk, bonjour

I want to know how to implement bonjour on windows, so that i can set up server on windows and access files in windows(server) using bonjour service from my iphone(client).

Can anyone tell me whether we have any java api for windows or any bonjour sdk for windows?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at Apple's [bonjour SDK page](http://developer.apple.com/bonjour). They provide an SDK for Windows there. I think it's written in C.

Answer (score 5):

This page describes how to develop for Bonjour for Windows. It also gives a link to the download page for the Windows API, including headers and libraries for C and Java.

http://support.apple.com/downloads/Bonjour_for_Windows

Answer (score 3):

Note that Bonjour is only for notifying other devices that a service is present on the network, it doesn't handle the actual file transfer.

There is a Java implementation called Rendezvous Proxy that broadcasts bonjour notifications, may be all you need on your server?

Web page is here: http://ileech.sf.net/RendezvousProxy/

Don't think the source is open though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, check the links on this page

http://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/bonjour.html