# Trying to run demo app using Bonjour, but it can't discover the server running on the same host

Tags: c++, windows, qt, bonjour

I've successfully compiled the demo app from [a tutorial on using Bonjour from Qt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-bonjour.html), but when the client runs, it can't find the server, even though the server is running on the same computer!

Both the client and server use only `dnssd.dll`. Am I missing something? Do I need to have some sort of a daemon running?

I have no experience with Bonjour so it's entirely possible I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975685/492336

It turns out I need to download and run the Bonjour Installer from Apple.

After I installed Bonjour Printer Services, the demo client discovers the demo server.